# Show proper date before 1970

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am inserting selected DOB into database in "yyyy-mm-dd" formate using jquery date-picker. But when I am selecting DOB before 1970 then it gives me wrong DOB. eg. we select "August 19, 1949" then it show "August 19, 2049" in future year that is wrong. We are showing DOB in front-end using below mentioned code :

```
echo $newDate = date("M dS, Y", strtotime($BirthDetails['date']));
```

So please help me !!!
I'm using cakephp 3.0
When I print `$BirthDetails['date']`, it gives me

```
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object
(
    [time] => 2011-08-19T00:00:00+00:00
    [timezone] => UTC
    [fixedNowTime] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of searching, I found out my answer. We just need to do some changes in `config/app.php` file under the `'App' => []`
replace

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
```

to

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'pl_PL'),
```

this is proper working in my scenario

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
// pass your date format 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y','17 Jan 1949');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/673359)**